# Modify SVG attributes within a sub svg image using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have posted similar questions to this which have been solved / worked around.

My current problem is:

I have a web page with a SVG object on it:

```
<object id="main" data="../images/svg/MainImage.svg" width="80%" height="80%" type="image/svg+xml" />
```

The MainImage.svg has an svg polygon and also another svg image on it called subImage. The contents of the MainImage.svg is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg id="mainimage" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1000px" height="600px">
  <polygon id="mainPoly" points="141,94 174,94 174,56 141,56" stroke="blue" fill="blue"></polygon>
</svg>
```

The SubImage.svg also has an svg polygon in it. The contents are:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg id="subImg" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1000px" height="600px">
  <polygon id="subPoly" points="141,94 174,94 174,56 141,56" stroke="blue" fill="blue"></polygon>
</svg>
```

I have some javascript:

```
function modify() {
   document.querySelector("#main").getSVGDocument().querySelector("#mainimage").getElementById("mainPoly").setAttribute("fill", "red");
}
```

This javascript changes the fill attribute of the polygon on the MainImage.svg file.

So far this all works :-)

I now want to be able to change the fill attribute of the polygon on the SubImage.svg file.

I have tried several different variations of:

```
document.querySelector("#main").getSVGDocument().querySelector("#mainimage").getElementById("subImage").getElementById("subImg").getElementById("subPoly").setAttribute("fill", "red");
```

but can't get it to work.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `ID` attributes must be unique. Instead of calling `document.querySelector("#main").getSVGDocument().querySelector("#mainimage").getElementById("subImage").getElementById("subImg").getElementById("subPoly")` you can simply call `document.getElementById("subPoly")` to select the same element.

Comment: Thanks for your reply unfortunately that didn't work. I've just realized that my SVG code didn't display in the question. The sub image is added to the mainimage using an image tag with the id="subImage". I think the problem is that the sub image is embedded into the main image. Any other ideas?

Comment: I don't see any reference to SubImage.svg inside MainImage.svg.  Have you missed a bit of the SVG?  `id` attributes have to be unique, so for example, you will need to correct the multiple occurrences of `id="subImg"`.

Comment: Hi BigBadaboom, I had problems adding the svg code to the post, and then copied the sub image code twice. I have changed it now. The code shown is the code I have tested and doesn't work. Any ideas?